# Prolog combining predicates

Tags: prolog, predicate, prolog-findall

Just a small question about Prolog. Say I have used the built in predicate `findall/3` to obtain a list and used the variable `X` as my output.

I'm wondering how I could then use this list in another predicate such as `last/2` to find the last element of this list. If you could include a small example too that would help greatly.

Comment: You should show what you've tried.

Comment: Why not `listbuilder(List), last(List,Y)`?

Comment: So i would only have to define one predicate?

Comment: I'm getting an error for undefined procedure: findall/2

Comment: `findall` takes 3 arguments

Comment: Nevermind, i have got it to work with your solution, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289286/correct-use-of-findall-3-especially-the-last-result-argument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since Prolog aims to be a *logic programming* programming language, there is nu such thing as *output* variables.

Nevertheless, say you know a variable `X` is *bounded* after a certain predicate and you intend to use this value when calling a new predicate, you can use Prolog's *logical "and"* `,/2`. I'm putting "*and*" between quotes because this *and* differs sometimes from the natural understanding of how "and" in natural language behaves.

You can thus use a predicate:

```
findall(A,foo(A),X),last(X,L).
```

To first find all occurences of `foo/1`, extract the variable `A`, put these into a list `X` and finally get the [`last/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=last/2) element of `X`.

You can then for instance use this in a defined predicate:

```
last_foo(L) :-
    findall(A,foo(A),X),
    last(X,L).
```

If you run this for instance with:

```
foo(a).
foo(9).
foo(b).
```

The results are:

```
?- foo(A).
A = a ;
A = 9 ;
A = b.
```

and:

```
?- findall(A,foo(A),X).
X = [a, 9, b].
```

Now the result to obtain the last is:

```
?- findall(A,foo(A),X),last(X,L).
X = [a, 9, b],
L = b.
```

or:

```
?- last_foo(L).
L = b.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation